# Node project with Node don't synchronize the node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, nuxt.js

I'm dockerizing a node project, using nuxt to build a Vueapp,

My idea is to make a npm install into container when is building, and then after the build is complete, and all modules are installed, have the folder "node_modules" synchronized with my local "node_modules" folder...

But when the build finished, my local node_modules still empty so i can't use the dependencies... :(

My **Dockerfile** file is this:

```
FROM node:16.20-alpine3.17

WORKDIR /usr/src/app


COPY package.json /usr/src/app
COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

RUN mkdir -p node_modules/.cache && chmod -R 777 node_modules/.cache

COPY . .
```

And my **docker-compose.yml** is this one

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - 80:3000
    environment:
      HOST: 0.0.0.0
```

My local node_modules..

[image]

I've tried to change the "volumes", i think that could be the way to fix this, because if i go to the docker container of the front-end, the "node_modules" folder contains all my depenencies... and in my local not.

[image]

Comment: Delete the entire `volumes:` block.  Your Dockerfile already creates a `node_modules` directory when you `RUN npm install`; you don't need to hide it with an anonymous volume.

Comment: @DavidMaze if i delete the entire volume block , my localhost don't synchronize with the docker container

Comment: Correct, a Docker container by design is isolated from the host filesystem.  You can use a host-based Node for day-to-day development and a container for integration testing and deployment if you want.  Also note here that the `node_modules` in the container may not be the same OS or C library stack as the host; you probably _don't_ want this directory synchronized with the host regardless.